# Why {{partial}} don't share controller with {{outlet}}

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a sidebar for my Ember.js app. The idea is create a `sidebar` template, and render its content depending on the route I'm browsing.

These are the templates:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    {{partial sidebar}}
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_sidebar">
  <h1>Message: {{msg}}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item number 1</li>
    <li>Item number 2</li>
    <li>Item number 3</li>
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="maincontent">
  Message: {{msg}}
</script>
```

The controller is completely trivial:

```js
AxpoEM.MaincontentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  msg: 'Hello world!'
});
```

The problem comes when I browse to `/maincontent`. The `{{outlet}}` is correctly filled with the `maincontent` template, and `{{msg}}` is correctly shown. But the `{{msg}}` tag in the `_sidebar` template is empty.

The Ember documentation says that `{{render}}` shares the controller with the main `{{outlet}}`, so I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `partial` view helper, don't affect the context, controller etc. So using:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  Foo
  {{partial "somecontent"}}
  Bar
</script>
```

Is the same like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  Foo
  Your raw content here
  Bar
</script>
```

In your case the `_sidebar` partial doesn't know about the `msg` variable because the bound controller is `ApplicationController`. And you setup it in `MaincontentController`. If you want this behavior you can change the `partial` view helper to `render`, and override the bound controller:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="col-md-3">      
    {{! use render since we can override the controller}}
    {{render 'sidebar' controller="maincontent"}}
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

remove the leading underscore from _sidebar
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sidebar">    
  <h1>Message: {{msg}}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item number 1</li>
    <li>Item number 2</li>
    <li>Item number 3</li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

This is the fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/wydtE/

Comment: Thank you! That works great. The next question now is that I don't want to set explicitly the template/controller for the sidebar. I just want it to be the one in charge of {{outlet}}. The application template is generic (just a two columns layout, as you can see), but I want the sidebar to show different things depending on the path, and it won't always be "maincontent".